What does the property specifier BlueprintGetter and BlueprintSetter do?
private:
    // UPROPERTY(BlueprintGetter=GetHealth, BlueprintSetter=SetHealth) ?????
    int32 Health;
public:
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure)
    int32 GetHealth() const { return Health; }
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void SetHealth(int32 InHealth) { this->Health = InHealth; }

If I don't use the property specifier BlueprintGetter and BlueprintSetter for the private variable Health, I can also use Getter and Setter function to access it in Blueprint.
BP without Specifier
But if I delete the comment and use the specifier, I can access the private variable Health directly in Blueprint.Doing so destroys encapsulation, which is the opposite of the purpose of Getter and Setter functions.
BP with Specifier
So what's the meaning of BlueprintGetterand BlueprintSetter?

If the getter and setter functions let you access the private member, you could just as well have made it public. In effect, that is what "properties" does in this case.

@BoP That's not the point. Even then these two property specifiers are meaningless.

Using "properties" means that you can code what looks like direct access of the private member, but the code actually calls the getter and the setter. However, if those functions don't do anything "interesting", you could just as well make the data public. Otherwise they are meaningless.

@BoP The key point is BlueprintGetter and BlueprintSetter specifiers are useless. Whether you write these two property specifiers or not, you can call getter and setter function in Blueprint.

You use "properties" because you don't want to call getters and setters. That's the only reason.

TLDR: the built-in getter/setter are replaced with your code.
If you specify BlueprintGetter then the default getter for your property (left node in your 2nd screenshot) will run your code. The same apply to the setter, so the left and right nodes in your 2nd screenshot will run the same code. With your trivial example, it makes no difference, but if you do some pre-processing in your setter or getter, you'll see that your custom get/set code runs with the built-in nodes as well. Try adding UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Set")); in your setter, you'll see it runs event with the light blue nodes.
The goal is to allow to modify the behavior of the default getter or setter nodes. It is really useful if you have existing Blueprints code using it and don't want to replace it, or you simply want to add custom code to any Blueprint access to the variable.
